# Relacionamentod e duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Galera, tenho duas tabelas e preciso relacioná-las.
Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```html
SELECT lancamentos .* FROM lancamentos
  INNER JOIN clientes ON lancamentos.cliente_id = clientes.id
  ORDER BY clientes.nome ASC
```

Porém preciso trazer o nome da empresa que fica na tabela clientes ... estou com uma baita dificuldade nisso ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No exemplo abaixo, criei um *alias* para cada tabela.

```
SELECT l.*, c.* 
FROM lancamentos as l
JOIN clientes as c ON c.id = l.cliente_id
ORDER BY c.nome ASC
```

Não é uma boa prática utilizar asteriscos, portanto, substitua pelo nome dos campos que for utilizar.

exemplo: `c.nome_empresa, c.empresa_tel`

Comment: Valeu Allan, mais uma vez tu me ajudando ..
Obrigado !!